# EmberJS - loading content trhu AJAX breaking

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I'm trying to add some content into an array named content. The **test** value is added correct. The content into the GET call isn't loading. Why this?

```
App.CustomerController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    content = this.get("content");
    content.push(App.Customer.create({ name: 'Test' }));
    $.get("/Customer/GetCustomers", {}, function (result) {
        for (var I = 0; I < result.customers.length; ++I) {
            content.push(App.Customer.create({ name: result[I] }));
        }
    });
  }
});

App.Customer = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null
});
```

Comment: Hwo dies `result` look like?

Comment: Oh, result is just a List<string>. The returning is simple: `return Json(new { customers = customers.ToArray() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. If I put an alert inside the loop, the results are displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the data returned from `'/Customer/GetCustomers'` look like?  Maybe you need to be accessing `result.customers[I]` inside your loop instead of `result[I]`?

```
content.push(App.Customer.create({ name: result.customers[I] }));
```

Comment: Oh, result is just a List<string>. The returning is simple: `return Json(new { customers = customers.ToArray() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. If I put an alert inside the loop, the results are displayed properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my original suggestion is headed in the right direction.  `result[I]` should not be returning anything useful since `result` itself is not an array.  It's a hash, with the `customers` property being the array that you're interested in using.

Comment: I've made the changes in the backend code, returning only an array. The problem still persists. Every object I'm adding out of the ajax call is added. However, every content I'm adding into the success function doesn't appear. Why this happens?

Comment: Solved: Your solution works fine, thank you. I was calling "this" inside the AJAX call, but I would call parent. So, I've created a variable named self, referencing the parent. THanks!